# Notepad++ replace all using regular expression

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have lines of numbers

> 16
>   18
>   19
>   21
>   24
>   25
>   26
>   30

How can I put commas at the end of each number using regular expressions. For example: 16 will turn to 16, and 18 will turn to 18, and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not completely clear to me.

**1. Only digits in a row and nothing else**

Then Bohemians answer is working.

```
^(\d+)$
```

and replace with `\1,`.

The `^` anchors the sequence of digits to the start of the row and the `$` to the end.

**2. The digits can be anywhere in the row together with other stuff**

Then tafoo85 answer is working:

`(\d+)` and replace with `\1,`.

But this will replace also "`tafoo85`" with "`tafoo85,`" and "`2fast4you`" with "`2,fast4,you`"

To avoid this behaviour and matching only "standalone" numbers, you would have to use word boundaries but those are not available in Notepad++.

Because Notepad++ regexes are very limited you would have to workaround this issue in four steps:

1. `^(\d+)$`and replace with `\1,`
2. `^(\d+)(\s)` and replace with `\1,\2`
3. `(\s)(\d+)(\s)` and replace with `\1\2,\3`
4. `(\s)(\d+)$` and replace with `\1\2,`

**3. Change only digits at the start of the row**

use only the start of the row anchor `^`

`^(\d+)` and replace with `\1,`.

Answer (score 0):

Find: ([0-9]+)
Replace with \1,

Answer (score 0):

Find: `(^[0-9]+$)`  (means the whole line is all digits - and capture it)
Replace: `\1,` (means the first captured group then a comma